# Aurelia Replace all browser native confirms with modal

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, aurelia

I have the function bellow and I would like to Replace this with bootstrap modal, was easy to do in the html but I am not sure how to do this in the java-script code, can someone give any advice?  thank you.

```
function() {
    let model = this.tagModel(true);
    if (!_.isEqual(this.originalModel, model)) {
      let result = confirm(`Are you sure you wish to leave?`);
      if (result) {
        return true;
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use aurelia-dialog? (https://github.com/aurelia/dialog) It's pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

Have you solved this already? Here's what I think you need to do.

First you need to get Bootstrap setup in Aurelia. janmvtrinidad has a good answer about that [Including bootstrap css in Aurelia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38026255/including-bootstrap-css-in-aurelia).

Then you need to use it. [Here's info on the modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/).

switching your `confirm` with `$('#myModal').modal(options)` where #myModal is the div in your html should work.